# How to get the actual music in Spotify using python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, spotify

I downloaded the Spotify App on my Windows 10 and installed. So I had the ideia of make a software that need to get the music that is running at the moment. Is it possible to get It? It os not necessary the code. I just want to know where to start, because I did not find anything about It. I would rather do It using python.

Comment: When you say "get the actual music", what do you mean - do you want to get the actual sound that is playing, or  information about the track that is playing?

Comment: Spotify has an API for current playing music https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/

Comment: I want to get the information about the track, @bouteillebleu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Get the User's Currently Playing Track** endpoint, documented here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/

The endpoint will return JSON that includes information about the track, for example:

```
{
  "context": {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/49znshcYJROspEqBoHg3Sv"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/49znshcYJROspEqBoHg3Sv",
    "type" : "playlist",
    "uri" : "spotify:user:spotify:playlist:49znshcYJROspEqBoHg3Sv"
  },
  "timestamp": 1490252122574,
  "progress_ms": 44272,
  "is_playing": true,
  "item": {
    "album": {
      "album_type": "album",
      "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/6TJmQnO44YE5BtTxH8pop1"
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6TJmQnO44YE5BtTxH8pop1",
      "id": "6TJmQnO44YE5BtTxH8pop1",
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 640,
          "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/8e13218039f81b000553e25522a7f0d7a0600f2e",
          "width": 629
        },
        {
          "height": 300,
          "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/8c1e066b5d1045038437d92815d49987f519e44f",
          "width": 295
        },
        {
          "height": 64,
          "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/d49268a8fc0768084f4750cf1647709e89a27172",
          "width": 63
        }
      ],
      "name": "Hot Fuss",
      "type": "album",
      "uri": "spotify:album:6TJmQnO44YE5BtTxH8pop1"
    },
    "artists": [
      {
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0C0XlULifJtAgn6ZNCW2eu"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0C0XlULifJtAgn6ZNCW2eu",
        "id": "0C0XlULifJtAgn6ZNCW2eu",
        "name": "The Killers",
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:0C0XlULifJtAgn6ZNCW2eu"
      }
    ],
    "available_markets": [
      "AD",
      "AR",
  ...
      "TW",
      "UY"
    ],
    "disc_number": 1,
    "duration_ms": 222075,
    "explicit": false,
    "external_ids": {
      "isrc": "USIR20400274"
    },
    "external_urls": {
      "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem"
    },
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem",
    "id": "0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem",
    "name": "Mr. Brightside",
    "popularity": 0,
    "preview_url": "http://d318706lgtcm8e.cloudfront.net/mp3-preview/f454c8224828e21fa146af84916fd22cb89cedc6",
    "track_number": 2,
    "type": "track",
    "uri": "spotify:track:0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem"
  }
}
```

If you want even more info about the track, you can use the `id` you get from this endpoint to call any of the **Track** endpoints here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/track-endpoints/. There are lots of fun things you can do, like audio features or analysis.